# how to search a treenode and return it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I wrote this function but I don't know how to write the rest of it
It should be something recursive which I don't know

```
  public TreeNode FindNodeByText(TreeView m, string s)
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = m.Nodes;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                if (n.Text == s)
                    return n;
                else
                    ??????????
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/7d86de70-21a4-4e95-a50f-b2d0538b7084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
public TreeNode FindNodeByText(TreeView m, string s)
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = m.Nodes;
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        if (n.Text == s)
            return n;
        else
            return FindNodeByTextInTreeNode(n, s);
    }

    return null;
}

public TreeNode FindNodeByTextInTreeNode(TreeNode node, string s)
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = node.ChildNodes;
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        if (n.Text == s)
            return n;
        else
            return FindNodeByTextInTreeNode(n, s);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - its the `node` param (fixed the answer).

Comment: by the way in your edit you should have said node.Nodes but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok... its just that `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode` class does not have a property called `Nodes`, it has `ChildNodes`. But anyway, I guess that the basic principle of recursion is covered here :)